# Rich Snippet Breadcrumbs Issue

Tags: breadcrumbs, rich-snippets

I followed this [article](https://www.byte.nl/blog/magento-rich-snippets-made-easy/) to how to add manually rich snippets in Magento. so i want to add the breadcrumbs part.

This is the breadscrumbs.phtml content:

```
<?php if($crumbs && is_array($crumbs)): ?>
<div class="grid-full breadcrumbs">
    <ul>
        <?php foreach($crumbs as $_crumbName=>$_crumbInfo): ?>
            <li class="<?php echo $_crumbName ?>" itemscope itemtype="http://data-vocabulary.org/Breadcrumb">
            <?php if($_crumbInfo['link']): ?>
                <a href="<?php echo $_crumbInfo['link'] ?>" title="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_crumbInfo['title']) ?>" itemprop="url"><span itemprop="title"><?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_crumbInfo['label']) ?></span></a>
            <?php elseif($_crumbInfo['last']): ?>
                <strong><?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_crumbInfo['label']) ?></strong>
            <?php else: ?>
                <?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_crumbInfo['label']) ?>
            <?php endif; ?>
            <?php if(!$_crumbInfo['last']): ?>
                <span>&rsaquo;</span>
            <?php endif; ?>
            </li>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ul>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

In the [webmaster](http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/richsnippets?q=http%3A%2F%2Ftrend.netlogiq.eu%2Fmasa-candela-de-bar-70x70%2F) you can see that the breadcrumbs it is loaded. But it does not shown in the result. Any ideea what I am missing ?

Comment: While the markup can be correct, google do not guarantee will show it. I have faced the same issue with amasty module. Sometimes switch from vocabulary to shema.org helps.

Comment: can you post me a link or example with schema.org ?

Comment: Also, with Google, it's optional for them to use any of the microdata markup. So if they don't think it's relevant, it won't show. Also, expect it to take a month or two as they rescan your site. Their using it won't be an immediate thing as in all things SEO.

Comment: You can save the headache and use: http://www.creare.co.uk/creare-seo-magento-extension or take a look at how they implementing it. It is free, magento connect URL also: http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/creare-seo.html

Comment: @B00MER i don't know how this module will interact with my needs(rich snippets). I checked the images i don't see anything about rich snippets

Comment: "Breadcrumb Structured Data
Breadcrumb links are wrapped in Google’s own rich snippet schema for improved structured data."

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
<?php if($crumbs && is_array($crumbs)): ?>
<div class="breadcrumbs">
    <ul>
        <?php foreach($crumbs as $_crumbName=>$_crumbInfo): ?>
            <li class="<?php echo $_crumbName ?>" itemscope itemtype="http://data-vocabulary.org/Breadcrumb">
            <?php if($_crumbInfo['link']): ?>
                <a href="<?php echo $_crumbInfo['link'] ?>" title="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_crumbInfo['title']) ?>" itemprop="url" rel="nofollow"><span itemprop="title"><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_crumbInfo['label']) ?></span></a>
            <?php elseif($_crumbInfo['last']): ?>
                <span itemprop="title" class="last"><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_crumbInfo['label']) ?></span>
            <?php else: ?>
                <?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_crumbInfo['label']) ?>
            <?php endif; ?>
            <?php  if(!$_crumbInfo['last']): ?>
                <i class="fa fa-angle-double-right"></i>
            <?php endif; ?>
            </li>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ul>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

please see it here on [Google](http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/richsnippets?q=http%3A%2F%2Fbrmdev.co.uk%2Fnewcures%2Fshop-by-category%2Fmedicines.html)